# Compute $\sum_{i=0}^{2n} (-3)^i$ by splitting the series into two parts.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

Compute $\sum_{i=0}^{2n} (-3)^i$ by splitting the series into two parts.

*How* do I split it into two parts? All I can tell so far is that the sum is going to be a positive number (probably) because any $i * 2$ is even, and any negative number to an even power is positive.

Edit:

I split it into $\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-3)^{2i} + \sum_{i=0}^{n - 1} (-3)^{2i +  1}$ but I have no idea where t0 go from there.

Comment: Does n have to be a whole number?

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, split the series into even and odd terms that is $$\begin{align} \sum_{i=0}^{2n} (-3)^i &=\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-3)^{2i}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-3)^{2i+1} \\ &=\sum_{i=0}^{n} 3^{2i}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 3^{2i+1}\\ &= \sum_{i=0}^{n} 3^{2i}-\sum_{i=0}^{n} 3^{2i-1}\end{align}.$$

It is just a calculation now.

Comment: Careful with the indices and bounds of the sums - in your second sum, $(-3)^{2i+1}$ includes the case $(-3)^{2n+1}$, which is not in the actual series.

Comment: @UtkuAlhan I copied the summation twice and forgot to fix the limits, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** If you're not sure about a series, it may be helpful to expand out a few of the beginning terms:

$$-3 + 9 - 27 + 81 - 243 + 729 \mp \dots - 3^{2n-1} + 3^{2n}$$

$$(-3 + 9) + (-27 + 81) + (-243 + 729) \mp \dots + (-3^{2n-1} + 3^{2n})$$

$$6 + 54 + 486 + \dots + 6 * 3^{2n-2}$$

$$6(1 + 9 + 81 + \dots + 9^{n-1})$$

--> Use geometric series formula

(Note that $3^{2n-2} = 9^{n-1}$)